# Vue Accordion with dropdown select filter. How to bind data

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I am trying to get a local Vue project working where there is an E-Library Accordion with 3 types of media and a dropdown button to filter between the types of media. I am also trying to get a color coding system going and I attempted this through created a class and trying to bind it (not working). I am trying to filter the media with a method and then applying that method as an @click event to each dropdown button, but I know this is probably poor practice or just not the correct way to do this. Can anyone point me in the right direction as to how to get these two features working correctly? Much appreciated.

This is my page that I am routing to and creating the code on for the Vue project:

```
<template>

<label for="accordion">Choose type of media:</label>

<select name="accordion-types" id="types">
  <option @click="filteredAccordion(index)" value="book">Book</option>
  <option @click="filteredAccordion(index)" value="dvd">DVD</option>
  <option @click="filteredAccordion(index)" value="stream">Streaming Video</option>
</select>

<div v-for="(accordion, index) in accordions" :key="index">
  <button :class="{red: accordions.type === 'Book' }" @click="toggleOpen(index)">
  {{ accordion.title }}
  </button>

  <div class="panel" :class="{open: accordion.isOpen}">
    <p>{{ accordion.content }} </p>
    <p>{{ accordion.type }}</p>
  </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      accordions: []
    };
  },
  created: function () {
    const appData = this;
    axios.get("data.json").then(function (response) {
      appData.accordions = appData.addIsOpen(response.data.accordions);
    });
  },
  methods: {
    addIsOpen: function(items) {
      return items.map(function(item) {
        item.isOpen = false;
        return item;
      });
    },
    toggleOpen: function(index) { 
      this.accordions[index].isOpen = !this.accordions[index].isOpen;
    }
  },
  computed: {
   filteredAccordion: function(items) {
      return this.accordions.filter(accordions => !accordions.type.indexOf(this.type));
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style>
.accordion {
   background-color: #eee;
   color: #444;
   cursor: pointer;
   padding: 18px;
   width: 100%;
   text-align: left;
   border: none;
   outline: none;
   transition: 0.4s;
 }


.active, .accordion:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
 }

.panel {
   padding: 0 18px;
   background-color: white;
   display: none;
   overflow: hidden;
 }

 .panel.open {
  display: block;
 }
 .red {
  color: red;
 }
 </style>
```

Comment: Is there a typo on line 12? `accordions.type` instead of `accordion.type`

Comment: OMG bless your heart - that was a really dummy mistake for that one! :D